# Reduzir a qualidade das imagens de uma URL no react native

Tags: react-native

O app que estou desenvolvendo, feito em react native, tem dentro dele muitas imagens de sites diferentes.
O problema é que algumas imagens são bem grandes e em aparelhos ruim ele trava o aplicativo em outros casos deixa o aparelho lento.
Minha duvida é, é possível reduzir uma qualidade da imagem dentro fazer reativo nativo sem passar por servidor intermediário?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image

Comment: Não fala nada de suporte ao react native.